# What kind of a stand setup is this?

Tags: studio, studio-setup, equipment-identification

What kind of equipment is this?
Saw this in a video and couldn’t figure out.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a "tent" lighting setup. The idea is to place above the subject a diffuser. Lamps are aimed so as to evenly illuminate the diffuser. Such a successful lash-up delivers highly diffused light to the subject. This method is preferred when the subject has a high polish like metals, glass and jewelery etc.

Comment: If I need to buy the “truss” system what should I be looking for?

Comment: @ Quintin Par  ---  Google --  tent lighting for jewelry. Also Google diffused lighting for portraiture. You can make a simple setup using a bed sheet. I used fiber glass curtain material, it is fireproof and OK for hot lights. You can light the tent from above. You can use plastic diffusing material used in ceilings when the lights are recessed. You can use rope or cable in place of the trusts. You can do this on the cheap. Just use your brainpower. If you have deep pockets buy a setup.